# how to place a fixed button inside a specific element

Tags: html, css

I need a button to scroll `story` to top when clicked.
But I need it inside the `story`, not outside.
Also, it must not be scrollable, so positioned fixed.
But if it is `fixed` - how to place it inside `story`, i.e. 14 px from right border of `story`?

```css
.story{
position:relative;
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
height:100vh;
background:#ddd;
overflow-y:scroll;
}

.gotop{
position:fixed;
right:14px;
bottom:0;
padding:14px 9px;
background:gold;
border-radius:45% 45% 0 0;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='story'>
<div class='gotop'>TOP</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) and a small change to your markup might work.

if you set `.gotop` to sticky and load it at the very bottom of your story. You can then force it to be stuck to the bottom by using `bottom: 0`

I use `float` here to push it to the right, which is pretty ugly. You can get rid if that if you use flex but I don't know about the rest of your markup.

```css
.story {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70vh;
  background: #ddd;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.gotop {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 14px 9px;
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 45% 45% 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='story'>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <p>Example</p>
  <div class='gotop'>TOP</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've written my code here :  https://jsfiddle.net/nbxcgdk9/

```
.story{
position: relative;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100vh;
background: blue;
overflow-y: scroll;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

.gotop{
top: 100%;
margin-left: calc(100% - 50px);
bottom: 0;
width: 50px;
padding: 14px 9px;
background: gold;
border-radius: 45% 45% 0 0;
cursor: pointer;}
```

Style as per convenience :)